# SqlConnection throws an error on connection test

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio

I'm trying to test the connection to msql server and it throws me the an error `System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: No message resource found for message property prop.servertype`. it passes all the way and stops on `con = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, user, password);`

```java
  private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        boolean conSuccess = false;
        String host, port, dbname, user, password, instance;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.e("SQLConfig", "Estou dentro do try");


                String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
                String conString;
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(port))
                {
                    conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + host + "/" + instance + ";DatabaseName=" +dbname;
                }
                else
                {
                    conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + instance + ";DatabaseName=" +dbname;
                }
                Connection con;
                Class.forName(driver);
                Log.e("SQLConfig", "Driver metida com sucesso");
                //con = DriverManager.getConnection(testCon);
                Log.i("Carlos",conString + " - User: " + user + " - Password: " + password);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, user, password);
                Log.e("SQLConfig", "Consegui fazer a ligação com sucesso");
                con.close();
                Log.e("SQLConfig", "Fechar ligação ");
                conSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("SQLConfig", "Não consegui fazer a ligação");
                Log.e("SQLConfig", e.toString());
                Log.e("SQLConfig", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Full error stack:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: No message resource found for message property prop.servertype
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Messages.get(Messages.java:120)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Messages.get(Messages.java:67)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.parseURL(Driver.java:374)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.setupConnectProperties(Driver.java:239)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:182)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
        at com.example.viewer.dbconfig$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(dbconfig.java:210)
        at com.example.viewer.dbconfig$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(dbconfig.java:181)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/SQLConfig: Não consegui fazer a ligação
    java.lang.RuntimeException: No message resource found for message property prop.servertype
    No message resource found for message property prop.servertype
```

Print from the phone:
[image]

When i click on the button "Testar ligação" it executes that which verify if the textboxes are not empty

```
        _btnTestCon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Verificar se os dados forem todos preenchidos ou não
                if (_editTextHost.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || _editTextInstance.getText().toString().trim().equals("") ||
                        _editTextDbName.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || _editTextUser.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || _editTextPass.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(dbconfig.this);

                    builder.setMessage(R.string.config_message_needMoreInfo)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.general_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                                {
                                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
                }
                // Testar a ligação
                else
                {
                    AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                    runner.execute();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I expect the DriverManager.getConnection to return the log.e.

Comment: you should use retrofit for background calls..

Comment: why is this question tagged mysql by the way? Are you really running an SQL Server database instance?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the full stacktrace and logging.
How are you executing your code?
Do you have an SQL Server database running on the expected host and port?

Check out the documentation: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html

> The URL format for jTDS is:
>
> ```
> jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
> ```
>
> where  is one of either 'sqlserver' or 'sybase' (their
>   meaning is quite obvious),  is the port the database server is
>   listening to (default is 1433 for SQL Server and 7100 for Sybase) and
>    is the database name -- JDBC term: catalog -- (if not
>   specified, the user's default database is used).

Your URL is for example:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:1337/instance;DatabaseName=dbname
```

Are you sure the URL is correct? 
Are you setting a port number or not?
Does the instance exist?
Does the property DatabaseName exist and do you pass the correct value to it?

Comment: And yes my url is correct the databasename exists as well

Comment: Which JTDS jar are you using exactly? Is it on the classpath?